# QML TextArea gets activeFocus (cursor is blinking) I can paste text with right-click context menu, but I can not type anything

Tags: qml, kde-plasma, plasmoid

I have made a custon plasmoid widget for KDE.It is a `PlasmaCore.Dialog{}` "window" , without background which slides in and out from right side of screen.Inside this window  I have  "append" some other widgets, I mean, I have used the qml files in a ObjectModel and used them in a ListView.

Untill now the concept of the plasmoid works fine.Except a small issue.One of the qml files, widgets, is main.qml from notes widget for KDE(org.kde.plasma.notes).The problem I am facing is that the `TextArea` of the widget gets `activeFocus`, the cursor is blinking inside `TextArea`,  I can paste text inside it but I can not type anything with keyboard.

The modified code of main.qml I used is in below link :

https://gist.github.com/cgiannakidis70/8a0ea61d7f18e803381159d7456e2135

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT 1

After thorough searching i found that this is a `PlasmaCore.Dialog{}` matter .What i found is that if I change the window `flags` from `Qt.X11BypassWindowManagerHint` so the window can slide out of the screen, to `Qt.Popup` the `active Focus` is on `TextArea` and can type whatever text .But this solution creates the problem of not sliding the window out of the screen edge.Anyway I will search for solution to the new problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use of flags `Qt.BypassWindowManagerHint` and `Qt.Popup`  I can slide the window outside screen edge and also type in `TextArea` inside the widget .